# Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: spacechem

Is there a comprehensive list of mouse/keyboard shortcuts for SpaceChem?

I read somewhere than you could change the priority of bonders using ctrl+scroll wheel. I would be especially interested in a shortcut to instantly place a bond+ instead of bond+/- and then having to right-click to change it.

Comment: There, I thought: Wow, easy points for a quick answer. But I also couldn't find anything existing on the net. Maybe that is a good thing to create, the community would like it.

Answer (score 11):

Let's start something :

- undo: <kbd>crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>
- redo: <kbd>crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>
- select speed: number keys <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>
- stop: <kbd>~</kbd>
- pause : <kbd>space</kbd>
- select : <kbd>shift</kbd> + mouse
- copy : <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + drag mouse
- enables/disables the ctrl actions in boss levels : <kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>
- debug mode : <kbd>F5</kbd>
- delete selected symbols : <kbd>Del</kbd>

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with these. I was hoping for more advanced functions.

Comment: Also, F1 through F4 enables/disables the ctrl actions (the one on boss levels). F5 will enable debug mode though I only know that FPS stands for frames per second.

Comment: @TNgo : I updated with your shortcuts and made it a community wiki to ease and allow further additions :)